# How to flip given input in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I encountered this question in my interview and had no clue regarding this. I will really appreciate the help.

I have a input file and I want to get the output file.

Input.txt:

```
**  **  **

 ## ## ##
    ## ##

 ## ## ##
 *** ***
 ooo oo
```

Output.txt:

```
*       
* #  #*o
  #  #*o
      *o
* ## #  
* ## #*o
      *o
  ## #* 
* ## #  
*
```

Comment: You're not using a good formatting method for this (see online help for proper formatting), so it's a little off. But it looks like they just want the output to be a transposition of the input when taken as a character matrix. So it's about reading in the text and viewing it as a 2D array of characters rather than a 1D array of strings, transposing, and then outputting as a 1D array of strings again.

Comment: @lurker, wouldn't that make the first line of the output `'* #  #* '`, rather than just `'*'`? Santos, were you given the rule for converting the input to the output? If not, what do you believe the rule to be? As lurker suggests_the formatting is crucial. Please edit your question to correct the formatting.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that's why I caveated my comment about the OP's formatting. It's unclear to me what format the input and output really are since some of the columns don't align (see for example the Input.txt line `## ## ##` versus `    ## ##`). The OP needs to make sure that the number of spaces shown is correct, and to use the 4-space indent (code) formatting, not the back-tick formatting per line. I'm questioning whether the problem statement has the file characters aligned exactly as shown in the original problem.

Comment: I've edited the input to match the output by adding some spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [luker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980550/lurker) described earlier in his comment to the question one should use `transpose` method to make "flip".

```
# reading input.txt
input = IO.read './input.txt'
# getting lines
a = input.split("\n")

# we need uniform length arrays
# so we first need to know max.length of the line
max_length = a.max{|x| x.length}.length

# fill all arrays with empty string to become of the same size
uniform_length_array = a.map do |x|
  a = x.split('')
  a.fill('', a.length...max_length)
  a
end

# flipping!
flipped = uniform_length_array.transpose

# we need some juggling before we output it to our users
puts flipped.map(&:join).join("\n")
```

Credit for the last line goes to [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) for pointing more concise syntax.

Also [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man) provided a [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32657921/1426097) for max length calculation in array of strings.

Comment: The [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method is the magic in here. As a note, you can always use `join` in place of `join("")` as the default is to join with no space. That means you can do: `flipped.map(&:join)` Also `File.read` or `File.readlines` might be more clear than `IO`.

Comment: As you are doing what @lurker suggested in an earlier comment, it would be a courtesy to reference that comment in your answer. You could write `a.map(&:length).max`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I didn't notice luker's comment. Sorry. I'll mention him too

Comment: Awesome .... code is working and I am able to understand because of the comments. I want to thank you guys for the help.

Comment: It isn't necessary to add "Update" or "Edit" markers in questions or answers. Instead, put the information where it needs to be to maintain proper flow and grammar. We can see what was changed if we need to.

Comment: @theTinMan accepted. But grammar is a tough topic for me. Will try to improve.

Comment: Don't worry about the grammar as much as trying to ask good questions and creating good answers, and remembering that SO aims to be a reference book, so think about reading a cookbook or Wikipedia or an encyclopedia and what sort of content they'd have. We can be a bit more informal and a bit more friendly, but still we're here to provide concise answers to concise questions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little benchmark for determining the maximum string lengths:

```
require 'fruity'

ary = 10.times.map { |i| '-' * (1 + i) }
# => ["-",
#     "--",
#     "---",
#     "----",
#     "-----",
#     "------",
#     "-------",
#     "--------",
#     "---------",
#     "----------"]

compare do
  max_length_length { ary.max{ |l| l.length }.length }
  map_length_max1   { ary.map(&:length).max          }
  map_length_max2   { ary.map{ |l| l.length }.max    }
end

# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> max_length_length is faster than map_length_max2 by 60.00000000000001% ± 10.0%
# >> map_length_max2 is faster than map_length_max1 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
```

This also applies to `min`:

```
compare do
  min_length_length { ary.min{ |l| l.length }.length }
  map_length_min1   { ary.map(&:length).min          }
  map_length_min2   { ary.map{ |l| l.length }.min    }
end

# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> min_length_length is faster than map_length_min2 by 2x ± 0.1
# >> map_length_min2 is faster than map_length_min1 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Clearly `ary.max` should be much more performant, because you need 1 cycle, instead of 2 in another solutions.

Comment: Yes. That's where benchmarks help, they make us think about the code. I learn a lot about writing clear but still fast code by experimenting with them.

Comment: Thaks for this lesson. I've never met real Ruby monk/ninja in my life ;)

Comment: You still haven't. I'm nowhere near that point, but there are some here who I bow to, very, very deeply.

Answer (score 0):

This method does not use `Array#transpose`.

**Code**

```
def flip(str)
  arr = str.split("\n")
  rndx = 0..arr.size-1
  (0..arr.map(&:size).max-1).map { |j| rndx.map { |i| arr[i][j] || ' ' }.join }
end
```

**Example**

```
str = <<_
**  **  **

 ## ## ##
    ## ##

 ## ## ##
 *** ***
 ooo oo
_

puts flip(str)
*       
* #  #*o
  #  #*o
      *o
* ## #  
* ## #*o
      *o
  ## #* 
* ## #  
*
```

**Explanation**

For the above example:

```
arr = str.split("\n")
  #=> ["**  **  **",
  #    "",
  #    " ## ## ##",
  #    "    ## ##",
  #    "",
  #    " ## ## ##",
  #    " *** ***",
  #    " ooo oo"] 

rndx = 0..arr.size-1
  #=> 0..7 
n = arr.map(&:size).max-1
  #=> 9
```

In:

```
(0..n).map { |j| rndx.map { |i| arr[i][j] || ' ' }.join }
```

when, say, `1` is passed to the first `map`'s block, and the block variable `j` is assigned that value, the inner expression is computed as follows:

```
a = rndx.map { |i| arr[i][1] || ' ' } 
  #=> ["*", " ", "#", " ", " ", "#", "*", "o"] 

a.join
  #=> "* #  #*o"
```

This returns the second row of the computed array (offset `1`).

**Alternative method**

```
def flip(str)
  arr = str.split("\n")
  col_ndx = (0..arr.map(&:size).max-1).to_a
  arr.map { |row| row.
                  chars.
                  values_at(*col_ndx).
                  map { |c| c  || ' ' }
          }.transpose.
            map(&:join)  
end

puts flip(str)
*       
* #  #*o
  #  #*o
      *o
* ## #  
* ## #*o
      *o
  ## #* 
* ## #  
*
```